# Why moving files stuck at the last file?

Tags: windows-explorer

[image]

I am moving tons of files and it stuck.

After the last file it's 99% complete and speed go to 0

Why

Answer (score 0):

It might be that a file is locked (in use) or it might the OS could be doing work that does not show in the transfer dialog.

- First, check for any application that might have one of the files open, e.g., *Visual Studio*, and close it. You can check what locks particular files with a third-party tool such as [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/).
- Second, if you decide to abandon the operation, try an alternate method of moving the files:

  - It is usually more efficient to *copy* large numbers of files, and then to *delete* the source, then to *move* directly, since when moving, after *each* file is successfully copied, the OS has to go back and delete it from the original location.
  - You might try Windows built-in [Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) utility, which can transfer large blocks of data directly.